# Defining constants in Logstash 7.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

My intent is to index in ElasticSearch N tables from an Oracle database. For that, I define one `jdbc` for each table in the input section. I don't want to repeat, for example, the location of the JDBC jar in each `jdbc` entry, so I tried to `mutate/add_field` to set the value once but this doesn't work. I get

```
Couldn't find any input plugin named 'mutate'
```

I tried `stdin` instead of `mutate` and it didn't work either. Any ideas how to set and use a constant?

```
input {
  mutate {
      add_field => { "[@metadata][lib]" => "/path/to/lib/ojdbc8.jar" }
  }

  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => [@metadata][lib]
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pwd"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT col1 from table1"
  }

  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => [@metadata][lib]
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pwd"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT col2 from table2"
  }

}
output {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "my_index"
        user => "kibana"
        password => "changeme"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alain Collins mentioned, you can use the environment variables. Here is an example:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "${JDBC_DRIVER_LIB}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pwd"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT col1 from table1"
  }
}
```

and then you can set the environment variable when you are starting up the Logstash process. For instance, if you are using command line to start Logstash process:

```
JDBC_DRIVER_LIB=/path/to/lib/ojdbc8.jar /PATH_TO_LOGSTASH_BIN_DIR/logstash -f YOUR_CONFIG.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you a clue - `mutate` is a filter plugin, and is not available in the input or output sections.

You might try using [environment variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html), which you can use in the input section.

Comment: can you edit the question to see how this would work?

Comment: I know it goes against some SO practices, but I'd rather teach you to fish.  There are pretty clear examples in the doc.  If you try them and they don't work, make a new posting and perhaps someone can help you.  Personally, I've never used environment variables in my config, so I'd only be guessing from the doc.